# exclusion of index.html in nginx rewrite rule

Tags: nginx

I have a website which I am rendering in https mode and I have written the rewrite rule in the `default.conf` like below:

```
listen       80;
server_name  hostname.com;
rewrite      ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
```

However, I need to exclude the index.html or `/` from rewriting. How can I write the rule to exclude the `index.html` or `/` from rewriting?

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for this, but here is example which excludes `/` and `/index.html` from rewrite. Also I've changed `rewrite` to more efficient `return` directive.

```
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
root /path/to/root/dir;

# exclude / from rewrite
location = / {
    index index.html;
}

# exclude /index.html from rewrite
location = /index.html {
}

location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```